# VBA - Efficient for each loop for big ranges

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am fairly new to VBA and am trying to figure out how to use a for each loop in a large range (500k).

I want to calculate several scenarios in a table depending on a probability that has the following format:

```
Group Type   | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3.

Probability  | 20%     | 30%     | 70%

Scenario 1   | 0       | 1       | 0 

Scenario 2   | 0       | 0       | 1   
....

Scenario 500k| 0       | 1       | 1
```

Unfortunately, my For each loop only works in the small range up to 10k - do any of you have an idea how I can use it better?

```
Sub ScenarioCalculation()
 
Dim propability As Double, random As Double, row As Long, col As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For col = 4 To 23
    For row = 25 To 100
        propability = Cells(12, col + 1).Value
        random = 0# + Rnd * 1#
        If random < propability Then
            Cells(row + 1, col + 1).Value = 1
            Else
            Cells(row + 1, col + 1).Value = 0
        End If
    Next row
Next col
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Dont use Excel for more than 10k rows, it's not a database.

Comment: Is not a for each loop you use and why is the loop values capped between row `25 To 100`? I don't really understand your real issue (is the code slow), i.e. what's not working with the code?

Comment: It seems you are randomly generating 0s and 1s in a given range. If so, you can use excel formula `=RANDBETWEEN(0,1)` which will randomly give you zero or one and then copy it over the range or you can enter a formula with control+enter in all the selected range at once. I think it will much faster that looping through each cell in vba. Yes, but it will be volatile and so you will have to copy it as values.

Comment: @Naresh - the 1 or 0 depends on the value of the cell in row 12

Comment: @TimWilliams .. I am not sure. But I think if we are comparing two values; one known and other random; then also probability of one being more or less than other should be 50%  like 0 or 1. If both values are unknown then it is 50%.. I think:)

Comment: @TimWilliams after comparing with your answer.. yes, you are right. 0.6 (or 60%) always have high probabililty as per your answer .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cell-by-cell operations are comparatively slow.  You can use arrays to improve performance.

This should be faster:

```vb
Sub ScenarioCalculation()
    
    Const NUM_SCENARIOS As Long = 10000 ' for example
    Dim propability As Double, random As Double, row As Long, col As Long, arr
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For col = 4 To 23
        propability = ws.Cells(12, col + 1).Value   'only need to read this once...
        Set rng = ws.Cells(25, col + 1).Resize(NUM_SCENARIOS)
        arr = rng.Value                             'create array from range
        'populate the array
        For row = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            random = 0# + Rnd * 1#
            arr(row, 1) = IIf(random < propability, 1, 0)
        Next row
        
        rng.Value = arr 'populate the range from the array
    Next col
 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is much better faster than my solution and it also works for large numbers of rows. (just tested it: 1sec vs 50 secs for 100k). Learned something new

Comment: Works much faster even for 500K rows

Answer (score 0):

create a long variable and use ranges:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim probability as variant
Dim col as integer

Set rng = Range("B2")


For col = 0 to 20
  probability=rng.offset(0,1).value
  For i = 1 To 500000
    random = 0# + Rnd * 1#
    rng.offset(0,2 + col).value = iif(random<probability,1,0)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
  Next
Next
```

This way you use Excels internal ability to use big numbers of cells and work on each row individually.
And as @Tim Williams showed: if you enclose that in a

```
On Error Goto EndThisSub
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ....
EndThisSub:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

it will be much faster.